# How to convert Nodejs counter readable stream example to simplified construction version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I refer to this doc

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#simplified-construction

**The `_construct()` method is never called in my version. Why?**

*Note: In simplified construction you provide the implementation of `_construct()` method in the constructor options `{construct() {...}, ...}`*

This is a working class version of a readable stream counter example:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

class Counter extends Readable {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this._max = 10;
    this._index = 1;
  }

  _read() {
    const i = this._index++;
    if (i > this._max) {
      this.push(null);
    } else {
      const str = String(i);
      const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8');
      this.push(buf);
    }
  }
}

const readable = new Counter();

readable.on('readable', function() {
  console.log('readable');

  let data;

  while ((data = this.read()) !== null) {
    console.log(String(data));
  }
});

readable.on('close', function() {
  console.log('close');
});
```

This is my not working simplified construction version:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const counter = new Readable({

  construct() {
    this._max = 10;
    this._index = 1;
    console.log(this._max); // This is never executed
  },

  read() {
    console.log(this._max); // This is undefined
    this.push(null);
  }

  // read() {
  //   const i = this._index++;
  //   if (i > this._max) {
  //     this.push(null);
  //   } else {
  //     const str = String(i);
  //     const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8');
  //     this.push(buf);
  //   }
  // }

});

counter.on('readable', function() {
  let data;

  while ((data = this.read()) !== null) {
    console.log(String(data));
  }
});

counter.on('close', function() {
  console.log('close');
});
```

The docs say:

```
const { Writable } = require('node:stream');

const myWritable = new Writable({
  construct(callback) {
    // Initialize state and load resources...
  },
  write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    // ...
  },
  destroy() {
    // Free resources...
  }
});
```

Now I'm confused. Thought initialization code belongs into the `_construct()` method?

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm on Node Version 14.9 but `_construct()` is added with 15.0. I'll resolve this question later with a complete working example for further reference.

Comment: Where do you see this `_construct` method? You keep bringing it up, but nowhere in your code or the link does it make mention of _construct

Comment: See [readable._construct(callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readable_constructcallback). In simplified construction you don't implement the method directly. You provide the implementation in the constructor options (`construct()` without leading underscore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment above,  `_construct()`is added in Node Version 15.x. For further reference, follows the working example:

```
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const counter = new Readable({

  construct(callback) {
    this._max = 10;
    this._index = 1;
    callback(); // Signal completion of initialization
  },

  read() {
    const i = this._index++;
    if (i > this._max) {
      this.push(null);
    } else {
      const str = String(i);
      const buf = Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8');
      this.push(buf);
    }
  }

});

counter.on('readable', function() {
  let data;

  while ((data = this.read()) !== null) {
    console.log(String(data));
  }
});

counter.on('close', function() {
  console.log('close');
});
```